# Having trouble with onchange and storing numbers in an array via textbox

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, click, onchange

I am having trouble with my onchange not working and storing numbers in an array via a text box.
What I want the code to do is to get statistics on the numbers inputted into the text box. I do this by having the user input numbers into the text box and hit the Enter key to display those numbers. The numbers should be put into an array before being put into a list to display the inputted numbers. However, I keep getting this error where the onchange is not triggering when hitting the Enter key or clicking off of the text box.

[Here is an image of the error I am getting when inspecting the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vipiS.png)

With the numbers stored in the array, I want to try to get the Mean of the numbers. But, I keep getting the error "NaN" which makes me think that my numbers are not getting stored into the array properly.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stats</title>
</head>

<p>Array is called numbers. numbers.sort();</p>

<div id="stats">

  <input type ="text" id="value" onchange="list()"> <!-- Getting the Onchange Error here -->

  <button id="button1" onclick = "list()">Enter</button>

  <ul id="list1">
  </ul>

<button id="stat_button" onclick="calculateMean()">Get Statistics</button>

<p id="mean">Mean= </p>

</div>



<script>

function list() {

      var liElement = document.createElement("li"); //Creating new list element//

      var ulElement = document.getElementById("list1");   //Get the ulElement//

      var input = document.getElementById("value").value; //Get the text from the text box//

      var numbers = []; //create Array called numbers
      numbers.push(input);//adds new items to the array

      //for loop//
      for(var i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        liElement.innerHTML = numbers[0];  //Puts the array into the list for display//
        ulElement.appendChild(liElement); //add new li element to ul element//
      }
  }


function calculateMean() {

      var meanTotal = 0;
      var meanAverage = 0;
      var meanArray = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < meanArray.length; i++) {
        meanTotal += meanArray[i];
      }
      meanAverage = (meanTotal / meanArray.length);

      document.getElementById("mean").innerHTML = meanAverage;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Not sure about the `onchange` problem, but `numbers.push(input)` will add *one* element to the array, a string that contains whatever the user entered in the field. You probably want something like `numbers = input.split(/[, ]+/)` to create an array by splitting the string on commas and/or spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it through addEventListener instead of inline like that:

```
document.getElementById('value').addEventListener('change', function(e){
    list()
})
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your input. Adding an event listener instead of inline fixed that error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Mean is always `NaN` is because your mean array is always an empty array when you start with. I think you were referring to a `numbers` array here.

You will have to declare the array outside the scope of the 2 functions, since it is the common to both.

And it is always a better idea to decouple `Javascript` and `HTML`. Bind your events in JS instead of inline event handlers.

Note: When you read the value from the input, it is a string, so convert it to a number before storing it in the `numbers` array.

**HTML**

```
<p>Array is called numbers. numbers.sort();</p>

<div id="stats">

  <input type="text" id="value">
  <!-- Getting the Onchange Error here -->

  <button id="button1">Enter</button>

  <ul id="list1">
  </ul>

  <button id="stat_button">Get Statistics</button>

  <p id="mean">Mean= </p>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('value').addEventListener('change', list);
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', list);
document.getElementById('stat_button').addEventListener('click', calculateMean);

var numbers = [];

function list() {
  var liElement = document.createElement("li"); //Creating new list element//

  var ulElement = document.getElementById("list1"); //Get the ulElement//

  var input = document.getElementById("value").value; //Get the text from the text box//

  numbers.push(input); //adds new items to the array

  //for loop//
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    liElement.innerHTML = numbers[0]; //Puts the array into the list for display//
    ulElement.appendChild(liElement); //add new li element to ul element//
  }
}

function calculateMean() {

  var meanTotal = 0;
  var meanAverage = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    meanTotal += numbers[i];
  }
  meanAverage = (meanTotal / numbers.length);

  document.getElementById("mean").innerHTML = meanAverage;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruLc8k6j/)**

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the advice about the event listeners rather than inline. That seemed to clean up the error involved with the onchange. Declaring the array outside the functions makes a lot of sense as well because I am going to be using it across several functions.

Comment: I noticed in your jsFiddle that the numbers you put into the array all display as 1 instead of the number inputted. Also the Mean seems to not be calculating correctly. Is there any way you can update this so I can better understand how to calculate the Mean with the numbers in the array? Thanks you!

Comment: @MizanShaikh Check the updated fiddle. Got rid of the for loop for now. If you want to read a comma separated list of values, then you will have to add additional logic.